# Unable to connect to remote mongoDB from docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker desktop v4.17.0 to dockerize my nodejs application. My nodejs application is connected to remote Mongo DB.
`mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster-test.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

When I use my mobile hotspot to run `docker-compose up` my node app connects to remote mongoDB but fails on my wifi connection, I don't know why. Throwing following error

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

My docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my-service
    image: my-service:latest
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /code/node_modules
    environment:
      - DB_URL=mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster-test.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
    command: npm run dev
    networks:
      - my-network
    expose:
      - 9608
    ports:
      - 9608:9608
    restart: on-failure
volumes:
  my-data:
    external: false
networks:
  my-network:
    external: false
```

**What I have tried ?**

*Disabling the firewall*

How can I mitigate this issue?

Comment: Can you please check if your IP is getting whitelisted on MongoDB side? Cause this is what error is saying... so maybe have a look

Comment: this can helps how to add your ip address to mongo atlas, https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/